# No input files and no such files or directory errors

Tags: compiler-errors, ide, codeblocks

I got a new laptop yesterday and I will be using it to complete my cs degree. I have practised programming before but never encoutered such a problem. I downloaded codeblocks and tried to run the common starting program hello world. But it did not compile and showed my the following error messages. Please help me

I tried deleting codeblocks and i downloaded it again, same issues. Then I tried dev c++ and it started telling me that there was an error saving the main.cpp files of my program

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try renaming the file or if that does not work go to File -> New ->  Empty File then copy paste the program and then save it in a new folder and make sure you put .cpp at the end of the file name (and Save as type: should be All Files).
That is how I do it most of the time.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).